# How can you change a path that a file is written to using streamwriter

Tags: c#

[image]This is my form guys,  I have everything working correctly but one part. 
(Textbox3.TextChanged) = Filename that the user inputs 
(Textbox4.TextChanged) = Export File Path: This textbox gives the user a chance to change the filepath to something other than C:\Temp, it uses folderbrowsedialog and displays the path to the textbox but when the form finishes it does not save it to the new path, it still saves in C:\Temp

Can someone help me figure out how to get StreamWriter to write to the new path if the user selects a different file path rather than saving it to C:\Temp?

```
 private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string textBoxContents = textBox3.Text;
    }

    private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox4.TextChanged -= textBox4_TextChanged;
        if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox4.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Filename = textBox3.Text;
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\\Temp").Length;
        string path2 = Path.GetFullPath("C:\\Temp");
        string docPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        string var = Path.Combine(docPath, path2);
        string var1 = Path.Combine(var, Filename);

        if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Filename).Equals(".txt", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\\Temp").Length;
            path2 = Path.GetFullPath("C:\\Temp");
            docPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            var = Path.Combine(docPath, path2);
            var1 = Path.Combine(var, Filename);
            _ = Filename;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a File Name");
            return;
        }


        using (StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter(var1))
        {
            int numpins = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            string basepin = textBox2.Text;
            int pinlength = basepin.Length;
            string formatspecifier = "{0:d" + pinlength.ToString() + "}" + "{1}";
            long pinnumber = long.Parse(basepin);
            string dig = textBox2.Text;
            string result = GetCheckDigit(dig);

            for (int d = 0; d < numpins; d++)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dig))
                {
                    throw new Exception("null value not allowed");
                }
                else
                {
                    dig = pinnumber.ToString();
                    result = GetCheckDigit(dig);
                }

                basepin = string.Format(formatspecifier, pinnumber, result);
                objWriter.WriteLine(basepin);
                pinnumber++;
            }



            objWriter.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("File has been created");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Change `"C:\\Temp"` everywhere to `textBox4.Text`. Write `C:\Temp` in `Text` property in Form Designer for the TextBox as initial value. And learn what `@` before string do, I see a misuse.

Comment: Oh WOW!! thanks that worked.